# Why a const list can't be used in a string literal when it can't be modified in any way?

Tags: dart

```dart
void main() {
  const list = [1, 2, 3];
  const string = 'This is a $list'; // Error
}
```

When I can't assign `list` a new value and modify any of its elements, why can't I then use the `list` in my string literal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dart doesn't have a concept of saying that a method call can be evaluated at compilation time (in contrast to `constexpr` in C++).  Therefore Dart cannot guarantee that calling a method on a `const` object returns another `const` object, and that includes the implicit call to `.toString()` when doing string interpolation.

For example, this is perfectly legal:

```dart
import 'dart:math';

final random = Random();

class Foo {
  const Foo();

  // Returns a string that is clearly not a compile-time constant.
  @override
  String toString() => random.nextInt(100).toString();
}

void main() {
  const foo = Foo();
  print('$foo');

  const list = [foo, foo, foo];
  print('$list');
}
```

Note that this doesn't apply to `.toString()` implementations for some built-in types (e.g. null, numeric, string, and boolean types) since they are known to produce constant values and because Dart does not allow creating derived classes from those types, so they cannot be overridden to do shenanigans like the above example.

Comment: Can you please tell me where can I find this line from "Dart doesn't have a concept of saying that a method call can be evaluated at compilation time".

Comment: I can't point you to the absence of something.

Comment: Note that the inability to specify that functions/methods calls can be evaluated at compilation time is also why `const` constructors can't initialize members from function calls.

Answer (score 1):

It's an interesting question, because some `const` things *can* be interpolated into `const` strings.  I checked out the [Language Tour](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour), and it gives this example, which is very close to your question:

```
// These work in a const string.
const aConstNum = 0;
const aConstBool = true;
const aConstString = 'a constant string';

// These do NOT work in a const string.
var aNum = 0;
var aBool = true;
var aString = 'a string';
const aConstList = [1, 2, 3];

const validConstString = '$aConstNum $aConstBool $aConstString';
// const invalidConstString = '$aNum $aBool $aString $aConstList';
```

The explanation given is that

> Literal strings are compile-time constants, as long as any
> interpolated expression is a compile-time constant that evaluates to
> null or a numeric, string, or boolean value.

They don't explain *why* (what the technical reasons are, or the motivations for making the language work this way), but it's clear that a `const` list does not evaluate to "null or a numeric, string, or boolean value."  So it just doesn't matter that your list is `const`—the string resulting from interpolation with that will not be a compile-time constant, so you can't use `const` with that string.

Comment: Regarding they "why": The `.toString()` implementations for null, numeric, string, and boolean types are known to produce constant values.  Since Dart does not allow creating derived classes from those types, they cannot be overridden to do shenanigans like I demonstrated in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67050280/).