# Dart: In constant expressions, operands of this operator must be of type 'num'

Tags: dart, constants, operator-overloading

I created a const class like so:

```dart
class MyClass {
  const MyClass(this.x, this.y);
  final double x;
  final double y;

  MyClass operator +(MyClass other) {
    return MyClass(x + other.x, y + other.y);
  }
}
```

Now if I try to create a new class by adding two `const` values:

```dart
const objectA = MyClass(1, 4);
const objectB = MyClass(3, 2);

const objectC = objectA + objectB;
```

I get an error:

```
In constant expressions, operands of this operator must be of type 'num'.
```

If I use `final` it works, though:

```dart
final objectC = objectA + objectB;
```

I was going to say it's because the operator overload method creates a new class at runtime, but `objectA` and `objectB` were also created at runtime and they're constants. So why can't Dart allow `objectC` to be `const`?

Comment: You're calling a function.  Dart has no way of indicating that a function call can be `const` (i.e., can be evaluated at compile-time).  That it is allowed for some core types such as a `num`/`int`/`double` is a special case.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/67050280/

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to define a constant operator that accepts and returns classes other than `num` in Dart.

You cannot use these operators as constant expressions, unless it only accepts and returns the type `num`.
Dart cannot ensure that the expression is actually constant.

To be more precise, what this error actually means is "The operator you are calling is not constant."