# In constant expressions, operands of this operator must be of type 'bool' or 'int' on Dart using switch/case with enum

Tags: dart

I have some simple code like this:

```
enum myEnum {
      foo,
      bar,
      baz
}
    
mixin myMixin {

  final Map<myEnum, double> values = {
    myEnum.foo: 0.3,

    myEnum.bar: 5.2,

    myEnum.ter: 91.3,
  };

  double getValue(myEnum key, { double a = 0.0, double b = 0.0 }) {
    final double tot = a + b;
    double c = 0.0;

    switch(key) {
      case myEnum.foo | myEnum.bar:
        -1;
        break;
    }

    return values[key]!;
  }
}
```

and it is generating this error:

> In constant expressions, operands of this operator must be of type 'bool' or 'int'.

in the line `case myEnum.foo | myEnum.bar:` but I cannot get the reason for it.

Any idea?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72779176/dart-in-constant-expressions-operands-of-this-operator-must-be-of-type-num) answer your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not writing correct Dart.
The way to match two different values in a switch is to have two `case` clauses:

```dart
case myEnum.foo:
case myEnum.bar:
  ...
```

The `|` operator is not defined on enums (usually, with enhanced enums you can declare one, it's a user-definable operator), and since the expression after `case` must be a constant expression, and `|` in constant expressions is only allowed for integers (bitwise or) and Booleans (Boolean or), the expression `myEnum.foo | myEnum.bar` is invalid in a number of ways:

- It's not constant.
- `myEnum` doesn't have a `|` operator.

You only got one of the errors.